# How to use custom variables in gitlab ci/cd?

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm struggling with gitlab ci/cd variables. I see so many conflicting examples. Anyhow, what I would like to know is how to use variables outside and within scripts.

For example, in a job config, can I assign a variable in the script section with a bash command?

```
some-job:
   variables:
      SOME_VAR: ''
   script:
      - SOME_VAR = $(<file_with_a_line_of_text.txt)
```

In the above case, I'm not sure if I can do this. But I need to populate a variable with the file contents (i.e. artifact). Also, when do I use '$' in front of the variable? Some examples I see using these formats:

```
"SOME_VAR" #in quotes, no dollar sign
"${SOME_VAR}" #in quotes, with dollar sign and wrapped with curly braces
${SOME_VAR} #no quotes, with dollar sign and wrapped with curly braces
$SOME_VAR #i.e. without the double quotes or curly braces
SOME_VAR #i.e. without the double quotes, dollar sign, and curly braces
```

So many variations of usage that I can see in examples but don't really know when to use each style. And I can't find one example online of a custom variable being set in a script using a bash command.

Comment: Maybe you should start with a shell introduction?

Answer (score 10):

When I'm setting variables in bash, I always do it without the spaces around the `=`:

```sh
VAR1="some string"
VAR2=23
VAR3=true
VAR4=$(cat /path/to/file.txt)
```

Let's go through these examples one at a time:

1. You can set a variable as a string by using quotes around the string.
2. You can set it to an int (probably a float too, but haven't personally used it)
3. You can set it to a bool
4. You can set it to the output of a command. The command is inside the command: `$(#command)`.

Now let's use them:

```sh
echo $VAR1
# some string
echo "This is my variable $VAR1"
# This is my variable some string
echo "This is my variable ${VAR1}"
# This is my variable some string
echo ${VAR1}
# some string
echo "Error code ${VAR2}A"
# Error code 23A
echo "Error code $VAR2A"
# Error code --- Note: the variable $VAR2A dosn't exist
echo "Error code ${VAR2}${VAR1}"
# Error code 23some string
echo VAR1
# VAR1
echo "VAR1"
# VAR1
```

This illustrates the difference between the different forms, but in general, you reference a variable's value with `$+variable-name`. Doing `"SOME_VAR"` or `SOME_VAR` just prints out the string "SOME_VAR" (ie, not referencing a variable at all).

The difference between `$SOME_VAR` and `${SOME_VAR}` is that the latter lets you use it when there is other content directly before or after the variable without erroring.

Answer (score 6):

> How to use custom variables in gitlab ci/cd?

Normally like in any other shell.

But note that `gitlab-ci.yml` is a yaml file and yaml has special parsings. Because of that in `script:` ex. `- echo bla` is the same as `- 'echo bla'`, because in yaml the content of `script:` is an array of strings that are later spitted by shell.

> how to use variables outside and within scripts.

Normally like in any other shell script.

> when to use each style

> ```
> "SOME_VAR" #in quotes, no dollar sign
> SOME_VAR #i.e. without the double quotes, dollar sign, and curly braces
> ```

when you want to have a string `SOME_VAR` literally

> ```
> "${SOME_VAR}"
> ```

is the same as `"$SOME_VAR"`. When you want to have the *content* of `SOME_VAR` variable literally.

> ```
> ${SOME_VAR} #no quotes, with dollar sign and wrapped with curly braces
> $SOME_VAR #i.e. without the double quotes or curly braces
> ```

When you want the content of `SOME_VAR` variable **after word splitting and filename expansion**. That means that `SOME_VAR='*'` and then `echo "$SOME_VAR"` will print `*`, but `echo $SOME_VAR` will print all files in current directory. You usually **always** want to quote expansions.

The form `${SOME_VAR}` is used if concatenated with some other string, ex. `$SOME_VARbla` is not `${SOME_VAR}bla`.

Do not use upper case variables in your scripts - prefer lower case. Prefer using upper case variables for exported variables. Be aware of clashes - `COLUMN` `PATH` `USER` `UID` are examples of already used variables.

> can I assign a variable in the script section with a bash command?

Shell is **space aware**. `var = val` will **execute a command named `var`** with two arguments `=` and `val`. `var=val` will assign the string `val` to variable named `var`. Do:

```
- SOME_VAR=$(<file_with_a_line_of_text.txt)
```

In gitlab-ci I would prefer to use `cat` in case I will want to move to alpine. `$(<` is a bash extension.

```
- SOME_VAR=$(cat file_with_a_line_of_text.txt)
```

There doesn't seem to be any point in setting providing `SOME_VAR` in environment with `variables: SOME_VAR`.

> When do I use '$' in front of the variable?

When you want to trigger variable expansion. Variable expansion substitutes variable name for the variable value.

Check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net . Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide a good shell introduction and https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete .

Comment: So regarding gitlab ci/cd, if I declare a variable in .gitlab-ci.yml under variables, that variable should be accessible to all jobs in each stage, correct? Is there a way to change the contents of that variable later in a job, so that another job gets the change? What I'm struggling with now is that I declare the var, change it in a job (I also echo it to see that it has changed), then when I use it in another job in the same stage, it has the original value and not the new one.

Comment: `that variable should be accessible to all jobs in each stage, correct` Depends. Doing `variables:` at "root scope" will export the variable to all jobs. Doing `variables:` at job scope will affect only that one job. See gitlab documentation. `Is there a way to change the contents of that variable later in a job` sure, just `var=value`. `so that another job gets the change?` No, each job is it's own process. Even each job is run in it's own environment. Tbh, I fear such question is a sign of misunderstanding how docker works and processes work - be sure to research these topics.

Comment: `What I'm struggling with now is that I declare the var, change it in a job (I also echo it to see that it has changed), then when I use it in another job in the same stage, it has the original value and not the new one` Use artifacts to transfer context between stages. In bash, you can use `declare -p` to serialize variable value, and then just `source` the file to deserialize it's value.

Comment: The specific problem I'm dealing with is DAST, and the api scanner is expecting the variable DAST_API_SPECIFICATION to point to the api spec. The problem is that I'm trying to use an artifact to build that api url, but only a script will be able to assign to that variable. Example: DAST_API_SPECIFICATION=$(cat api_url.txt)/swagger.json, but this doesn't work because the var needs to be declared first.

Comment: If I don't use DAST_API_SPECIFICATION, it tries to look for a /zap/wrk directory and fails because it doesn't exist. I don't want to use custom zap endpoints for this one

Comment: `this doesn't work because the var needs to be declared first` See `export` command in shell, if it's missing.